# figuring out how to find the average of entered numbers

Tags: python

here is my current code:

```
total = 0.0
count = 0
data = input("Enter a number or enter to quit: ")
while data != "":
    count += 1
    number = float(data)
    total += number
    data = input("Enter a number or enter to quit: ")
    average = total / count
    if data > 100:
        print("error in value")
    elif data < 0:
        print("error in value")
    elif data == "":

print("These", count, "scores average as: ", average)
```

The only problem now is "expected an indent block"

Comment: Seems all you have to do is move your final print() into the block for your final elif. What you have should work.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something cool like

```
my_list = list(iter(lambda: int(input('Enter Number?')), 999)) # Thanks JonClements!!
print sum(my_list)
print sum(my_list)/float(len(my_list))
```

if you wanted to do conditions, something like this would work

```
def getNum():
   val = int(input("Enter Number"))
   assert 0 < val < 100 or val == 999, "Number Out Of Range!"
   return val

my_list = list(iter(getNum, 999)) # Thanks JonClements!!
print sum(my_list)
print sum(my_list)/float(len(my_list))
```

Comment: Why not just `my_list = list(iter(lambda: int(input('Enter Number?')), 999))` and save yourself an import? :)

Comment: so if i wanted to put an error if anything is above 100 but not 999 what do you think i should try?

Comment: and now alter it so that there would be only a single iteration over the data :P

Comment: im assuming this is user input not machine input as such it would take  a whole lot of number entering to make any noticable difference

Comment: not really, the only issue now is getting 999 to end the process and output the average.

Comment: @ErikAllik For a laugh then: `total, n = map(sum,zip(*zip(iter(lambda: int(input('Enter Number?')), 999), iter(lambda: 1, None))))` :)

Comment: Clever indeed! and actually seems to scale to arbitrarily large data sets!

Comment: now the only issue is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/jus.py", line 10, in <module>
    if data > 100:
TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()

Answer (score 0):

To calculate an average you will need to keep track of the number of elements (iterations of the while loop), and then divide the sum by that number when you are done:

```
total = 0.0
count = 0
data = input("Enter a number or enter 999 to quit: ")
while data != "999":
    count += 1
    number = float(data)
    total += number
    data = input("Enter a number or enter 999 to quit: ")
average = total / count
print("The average is", average)
```

Note that I renamed `sum` to `total` because sum is the name of a built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0.0
count = 0
while True:
    data = input("Enter a number or enter 999 to quit: ")
    if data == "999":
        break
    count += 1
    total += float(data)
print(total / count)
```